# How to delete all selected option in select using reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sizes-antd-4-18-3-forked-mvr3r).

I am trying to do following.

When I am choosing some options form second input and then changing first input selected value(s) the second input values should be deleting.

I try `useState` hook, but it not helping, the second input does not changing `defaultValue` into `undefined`.

How can I resolve that?

Here is my code:

```
    import { Select } from "antd";

    const { Option } = Select;

    const children = [];
    for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
      children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
    }

    const SelectSizesDemo = () => {
      const [clearAll, setClearAll] = useState(undefined);
      const handleChange = () => {
        setClearAll(undefined);
      };
      return (
        <>
          <Select defaultValue="a1" onChange={handleChange} style={{ width: 200 }}>
            {children}
          </Select>

          <Select
            mode="tags"
            placeholder="Please select"
            defaultValue={clearAll}
            onChange={handleChange}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            {children}
          </Select>
        </>
       );
     };

    ReactDOM.render(<SelectSizesDemo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: If not default value, then what else do you wanna set to select, Select can't take undefined, It doesn't know what to do with undefined. Try setting It to some other default value. like an empty string : ""

Comment: Select component's defaultValue is undefined? Probably, this is problem. You change the inital variable of clearAll to '{}' .

Comment: in initial state I am using `undefined` because when component render their is no data to show, if I put `null` or `{}` it will show in my select blank selected option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really are not clear with what you want in your question, but here is an answer.

**EDIT:** You so horrendously have explained your question. I'm not sure whether or not you want to delete all of the options in the second select when one in the top is selected, or if you want to delete ALL of the options, or just delete the one that is selected. So, here are both solutions. What do you exactly mean by *"I need to just show nothing in second select input"*???

*Remove all from bottom select when one in the top has a selection:*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

const SelectSizesDemo = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = () => {
    setSelected(true);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Select defaultValue="a1" onChange={handleChange} style={{ width: 200 }}>
        {children}
      </Select>

      <Select mode="tags" placeholder="Please select" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        {!selected ? children : null}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SelectSizesDemo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

*Remove just the selected one in the top from the bottom:*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

const SelectSizesDemo = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
  const handleChange = (val) => {
    setSelectedOption(val)
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Select defaultValue="a1" onChange={handleChange} style={{ width: 200 }}>
        {children}
      </Select>

      <Select mode="tags" placeholder="Please select" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        {children.filter(obj => obj.key !== selectedOption)}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SelectSizesDemo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Check the last one working on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sizes-antd-4-18-3-forked-ut8qp?file=/index.js

Comment: When the user makes a selection in the top select input, the bottom `selected options` should be removed. I mean the bottom select should be empty

Comment: That is exactly what this code does. Enjoy.

Comment: your code is deleting all options from second select dropdown. I need to just show nothing in second select input

Comment: My god... Then write a ternary operator within the select.

Comment: Check my edit @someone